# Put form fields two per line in bootstrap form

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap (version 3) and in the form, I am trying to put these fields two per line, but i cant figure it out how to do it.. Here you can see it in [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/uwludvRUBB) what i have done..

```
<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="form-group">
  <legend>1st sth</legend>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="select">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">                      
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="name">
   </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="select">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">                      
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="name">
   </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="select">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">                      
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="name">
   </div> 
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the rows in a div. `<div class="rows">`.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="form-group">
  <legend>1st sth</legend>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="select">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">                      
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="name">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="select">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">                      
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="name">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="select">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">                      
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="name">
   </div> 
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

[bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/PkciAkkRU0)